# Error converting a char[] string to uppercase

Tags: c++

This code is giving me an error that `sptr` was not declared in the `while` loop.

```
#include<iostream>

#include<ctype.h>

#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void convertToUppercase (char *s);

main()

{
    {
    
char s [40]="Welcome to gbk gang";

cout<<"Before converting The string is! "<<s<<endl;

void *convertToUppercase(s) ;


cout<<"After converting The string is! "<<s<<endl;}



void convertToUppercase(char *sptr)


    while(*sptr!='\0')

    {
        if(islower(*sptr))
    }

return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Please post a whole code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code shown has multiple syntax mistakes.

Starting with a spurious `{` that causes the code from `void convertToUppercase(char *sptr)` onward to become part of `main()` rather than be in a separate function definition.  `void convertToUppercase(char *sptr)` itself should not compile inside of `main()`, you should have gotten an error about that. But `while(*sptr!='\0')` would also fail to compile because there is no `sptr` variable declared in `main()`.

You need to remove that spurious `{`. Then `void convertToUppercase(char *sptr)` would be the start of a new function definition properly.

But you still have 2 other mistakes.

`void *convertToUppercase(s) ;` does not call the `convertToUppercase()` function. It declares a `void*` variable named `convertToUppercase` that points at the 1st `char` of `s[]`.

And `if(islower(*sptr))` is incomplete.

The code should look more like this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

void convertToUppercase (char *s);

int main()
{   
    char s[40] = "Welcome to gbk gang";

    cout << "Before converting The string is! " << s << endl;

    convertToUppercase(s);

    cout << "After converting The string is! " << s << endl;

    return 0;
}

void convertToUppercase(char *sptr)
{
    while (*sptr != '\0')
    {
        unsigned char ch = static_cast<unsigned char>(*sptr);
        if (islower(ch)) {
            *sptr = static_cast<char>(toupper(ch));
        }
        ++sptr;
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/ihKSMh)